# Python - regular expressions - find every word except in tags

Tags: python, regex

How to find all words except the ones in tags using RE module?

I know how to find something, but how to do it opposite way? Like I write something to search for, but acutally I want to search for every word except everything inside tags and tags themselves?

So far I managed this:

```
f = open (filename,'r')
data = re.findall(r"<.+?>", f.read())
```

Well it prints everything inside `<>` tags, but how to make it find every word except thats inside those tags?
I tried `^`, to use at the start of pattern inside `[]`, but then symbols as `.` are treated literally without special meaning.
Also I managed to solve this, by splitting string, using `'''\= <>"'''`, then checking whole string for words that are inside `<>` tags (like align, right, td etc), and appending words that are not inside <> tags in another list. But that a bit ugly solution.

Is there some simple way to search for every word except anything that's inside `<>` and these tags themselves?
So let say string `'hello 123 <b>Bold</b> <p>end</p>'`
with `re.findall`, would return:

```
['hello', '123', 'Bold', 'end']
```

Comment: If you're working with HTML, have you considered something like html5lib instead of trying to work out the regexes yourself?  http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/

Comment: Well I'm looking what RE is capable of. Or is there no simple solution for such problem? I only found that you can exclude literal characters inside [], but what about constructed classes like <.*?>.

Comment: Regular expressions can indeed do many things, but that doesn't mean you should use them to reinvent wheels, particularly with things like HTML, for which parsing is actually rather complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `re.compile(r'<[^>]+>').sub('', string).split()` should do the trick.

You might want to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) about processing context-free languages using regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex for this kind of task is not the best idea, as you cannot make it work for every case.

One of solutions that should catch most of such words is regex pattern

```
\b\w+\b(?![^<]*>)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) using a regular expression, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) makes it very easy to get just the text from an HTML document:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
text = "".join(soup.findAll(text=True))
```

From there, you can get the list of words with `split`:

```
words = text.split()
```

Comment: It says there no such module. I suppose its not installed on default Python?

Comment: It's not part of the standard library, no. Follow the link to find out how to download and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Strip out all the tags (using your original regex), then match words.

The only weakness is if there are `<`s in the strings other than as tag delimiters, or the HTML is not well formed. In that case, it is better to use an HTML parser.